# Xml Literals in VB.Net prevent escaping

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, escaping, xml-literals

I am experimenting with using VB.Net's Xml Literals as a templating system for generating HTML. What I am wondering if there is any way to control the escaping. For example if I have code similar to the following

```
Dim param1Value as String = "test"
Dim html = <div>
               <a id="myLink" href="<%= "/mysite/myfile?param1=" + param1Value + "&param2=test2" %>"
           </div>
```

This will produce a link with the ampersands xml encoded (`&amp;`).  Currently, I am just un-escaping these when transforming the xmlElement to a string.  I am assuming that is my only option as anything else produces invalid XML, but I was wondering if there was any way to specify that an XML Literal is a raw value and does not need Xml Escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years ago, I created an [ASP.NET MVC View Engine using VB.NET XML Literals](https://vbmvc.codeplex.com/) in which I had to solve this exact problem. There was no way to tell the Xml literals part of `vb.net` to ignore `&` characters. My particular scenario was trying to include HTML entities (like `&copy;`) within the Xml literals.

What I ended up with was using `<amp />` in all the places where I needed the `&` character within an XML Literal and then just doing a `.Replace("<amp />", "&")` when rendering the HTML. See the `Render` method in [VbView.vb](https://vbmvc.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#VbMvc/VbView.vb).

Comment: This is similar to the solution I came up with.  I thought maybe there was some other way to do this, but unfortunately it appears there isn't.

Comment: I was hoping that with the new open source compiler, there might be a way to create a real solution, but I doubt I'll have time to work on something like that.